# Core data and distributed object

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, core-data

Dear Community.
I try to release multiuser using core data. I was using a client-server bonjour connectivity. How it work now :
server part:

```
- (void)startBroadcasting;
{
receiveSocket = [[NSSocketPort alloc] init];
int receivePort = [self portFromSocket:receiveSocket];
NSLog(@"NETWORK: port is %d",receivePort);
myConnection = [[NSConnection alloc] initWithReceivePort:receiveSocket
                                                sendPort:nil];
[myConnection setRootObject:self];

myService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:kDomainName 
                                            type:kServiceName 
                                            name:kServerName
                                            port:receivePort];
[myService setDelegate:self];
[myService publish];
}

- (byref NSArray*)allObjects
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Carrier" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setIncludesSubentities:YES];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
[request release], request = nil;

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@:%@ error: %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
    return nil;
}
return objects;
}
```

Client part:

```
- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService*)service
{
NSLog(@"%@:%@ netServiceDidResolveAddress find something\n", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

NSConnection *clientConnection = nil;
NSSocketPort *socket = nil;
//NSData *address = [[service addresses] lastObject];
//u_char family = ((struct sockaddr*)[address bytes])->sa_family;
//socket = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initRemoteWithProtocolFamily:family 
//                                                 socketType:SOCK_STREAM 
//                                                   protocol:IPPROTO_TCP 
//                                                    address:address];
socket = [[NSSocketPort alloc] initRemoteWithTCPPort:[service port]
                                                host:[service hostName]];
clientConnection = [NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:nil 
                                                  sendPort:socket];
[clientConnection enableMultipleThreads];
[self setServer:[clientConnection rootProxy]];

[socket release], socket = nil;
[service stop];
[service release];
// testing connection:
[server ping];
NSArray *allObjects = [server allObjects];
[carriersArrayVisible setContent:allObjects];

}
```

Entity Carrier is a head of my tree objects.
Database size is 220M.
Everything work but i can't using that way because:
1. while i have update on server, i make delete for some "Carrier" objects, and this case product

> CoreData could not fulfill a fault for

error if i try to sort my array on client side by column.

1. This way product a lot of freezes of server and client user interface while data loading. I understand, what i can put a progress loading, but i don't understand how i can know a data progress sending, this is working behind scenes as i see. Network connection is perfect, and on local computer running client and server i have same effects.
2. I tried too many times to make sync my managedobjectcontext for client computer (probably this may be a better way), but i have some point, which i don't understand there:
   a) how i can do a whole copy from external moc to local moc
   b) may i create on server other copy of local moc to using by remote clients? attemt to create moc and attach to existing persistent store was fail, moc was empty...

Maybe somebody can share experience or suggest a good examples?

Comment: I have just been trying to get my head around core data for the first time.  And I am not sure this is related, In what I have just read. The data file for the data store is normally stored in a xml type file, core data has to load the whole file. But you can change it to an SQLite type database, which only loads what needed at the time. Thus being faster. There are some big caveats in using a  SQLite, especially if you have things setup already.  (on page 22 of this beginners example http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php)

Comment: I has sql type of course, XML don.t work fine at big databases. My solution was - I change design of my application and avoid removing. All new object of managed object context is have all data inside, this is what I don.t understand when design application was created at first.